# Access multiple projects using a single service account on google dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-cloud-iam

Is there any way to create a single service account that can access multiple dialog flow projects on google cloud? Is this even supported by google cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You'll need to grant that service account permissions in the desired projects. The roles that you grant depends on what you want the service account to do. Take a look at the [access control documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/access-control#top_of_page) for Dialogflow to more information on the distinct roles available.